# how to check if a directory was created by apt-get

Tags: aptitude

I want to check if a particular directory (like `/usr/kde`) was created and is currently managed by `apt-get`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apt is a front end to your real package manager. Typically dpkg on a GNU/Debian derived systems (such as Ubuntu). In this case you should use:

```
dpkg -S /usr/kde
```

But in other systems such as PCLinuxOS, apt is used to manage rpm pakcages. In this case the command is:

```
rpm -qf /usr/kde
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfect. And wow, learned something new, I never knew that `apt-get` can also be used on RPM based systems, I always thought it is very closely related to `dpkg` and in any case Debian-only (or any Debian derivate).